# Unknown error on Facebook API through R.

Tags: r, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to download all the posts from a facebook page through RFacebook, but when the page has an high number of posts (over 400 or so), the script stops, returning the error

> "Error in callAPI(url = url, token = token) :    An unknown error has occurred." at the line where I call the getPage.

```
library(Rfacebook)
library(stringr)
load("fb_oauth")
token=fb_oauth
page<-getPage("bicocca", token, n = 100000, since = NULL, until = NULL, feed = TRUE)
noSpaceMsg<-str_replace_all(page$message, "[\r\n]" , "")
output<-as.data.frame(cbind(page$from_name,page$id, noSpaceMsg, page$created_time, page$type, page$link, page$likes_count, page$comments_count, page$shares_count))
colnames(output)<-c("username","msgid", "message", "created_time", "type", "link", "likes", "comments", "shares")
write.csv(output, "bicocca.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

Where is the problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: try investigating the source code of getPage and determine where the error occurs within that function. Paste that here

Comment: This is the case when n>100:
 `## retrying 3 times if error was found
   error <- 0
   while (length(content$error_code)>0){
    cat("Error!\n")
    Sys.sleep(0.5)
    error <- error + 1
    content <- callAPI(url=url, token=token)  
    if (error==3){ stop(content$error_msg) }
   }
   new.df <- pageDataToDF(content$data)
   df.list <- c(df.list, list(new.df))

   if (!is.null(since)){
    dates <- formatFbDate(new.df$created_time, 'date')
    mindate <- min(dates)
   }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with the API, not with the R package. When I try to do the query in the Graph API Explorer [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=bicocca%2Fposts%3Fsince%3D2014-12-01%26until%3D2014-12-31%26debug%3Dall&version=v2.3&), I get an error too. No idea why.

One way around this is to query month by month, wrapping the getPage function in a try command:

```
page <- 'bicocca'
dates <- seq(as.Date("2010/10/01"), as.Date("2015/04/20"), by="month")
n <- length(dates)-1

df <- list()

for (i in 1:n){
    cat(as.character(dates[i]), " ")
    try(df[[i]] <- getPage(page, token, since=dates[i], until=dates[i+1]))
    cat("\n")
}

df <- do.call(rbind, df)
```

This will not give you all the posts, but probably most of them.

Comment: For some months I still get the same error, but I think this is the best possible solution, thank you.